# Segue launching but viewDidLoad not firing for new ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a little issue with launching a segue from code.

What I want to do in my app:

1. Logs into a website with a POST call.
2. When it gets a successful response from that login attempt it calls a function to change VC with a `performSegueWithIdentifier` call.
3. When the new view controller loads it populates a webview with another page from the site that the app just logged into

So far I am getting as far as the segue call. It calls can pushes to the new VC (or to somewhere at least), as it gets rid of the image being displayed by the old VC, but it doesn't cause the new view controller to populate the webview.

Code calling the function:

```
....

success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){

            ...

          [self blah];

            ...
      }
....
```

Code in that function:

```
- (void)blah{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"toMap" sender: self];
    NSLog(@"segue to map");
}
```

Code in the `viewDidLoad` of the new VC.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSLog(@"mapViewController");

    NSString *URLAddressForMap = @"this is where the link to the map goes";
    NSURL *urlForMap = [NSURL URLWithString:URLAddressForMap];
    NSURLRequest *loadMap = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlForMap];

    [myWebView loadRequest:loadMap];
}
```

This is the function that is not being fired by the segue. I know that it is not getting fired because I do not see any output form this line in the logs: `NSLog(@"mapViewController");`

Comment: Did you set the custom class for the corresponding scene in your storyboard to the class name of your mapViewController?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Are you talking about in the connection manager?

Comment: In your storyboard, select your mapViewController, then click on the Identity Inspector.  The first item should be Custom Class, and the Class name should be set to the name of your mapViewController class.

Comment: That solved it! Thank you very much! I was banging my head against the wall trying to figure that one out!

Comment: Done :) Thank you! I don't suppose you know much about AFNetworking or POST requests to login to a website?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with AFNetworking, and I've yet to do any POST requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your storyboard, select your mapViewController, then click on the Identity Inspector. The first item should be Custom Class, and the Class name should be set to the name of your mapViewController class.